# Should 'repent' and 'believe' be understood as often referring to the same event or act in the process of salvation?

Tags: greek, word-study, soteriology, word-choice

Should repentance and belief at time be understood to refer to the same thing or two different ways of describing the same mental change? Again my suggestion isn't that they mean the exact same thing, but often they can refer to the exact same thing. I have basically 3 main reason's why I think this makes the most sense of certain passages in the Bible.

1. **Significant lexiconical overlap:** The Greek word for repent in a variety of salvation contexts is μετανοέω. It is defined basically in dictionaries as to think afterward or to change your mind. If you begin to believe in something that you never believed before, such as in the Gospel, you necessarily change your mind. So logically in that context they would be referring to the same event.
2. **Well, you never see Clark Kent and Superman in the same place at the same time:** In a variety of scriptures related to the gospel and salvation, you never see repent and believe found in the same verse. *There is one exception, in Mark 1:15, where it seems that the two words are used to describe the same action:*

> Mark 1:15 “The time is fulfilled, and the kingdom of God is at hand; **repent and believe** in the gospel.”

*Here it is noteworthy that repentance comes first and then belief (which is opposite to the way I've been taught growing up where repentance was a result of belief). It seems that the instruction is to change your mind and believe in the gospel or in other words, change your mind towards belief in the gospel.*

3. **The two words seem at times to be interchangeable:** There are scriptures that involve repentance that could be exchanged with belief without changing the overall meaning.  For example in the first post-resurrection Gospel sermon by the Apostle Peter, belief isn't mentioned once, but repentance is:

> Acts 2:38 And Peter said to them, **“Repent and be baptized** every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ for the forgiveness of your sins, and you will receive the gift of the Holy Spirit.

The instructions are quite similar to:

> Mark 16:16 Whoever **believes and is baptized** will be saved, but whoever does not believe will be condemned.

...or consider Acts 26:20 where **repent** and **repentance** could be interchanged with **believe** and **belief** without significantly changing the meaning:

> Acts 26:20 but declared first to those in Damascus, then in Jerusalem and throughout all the region of Judea, and also to the Gentiles, that **they should *repent* and turn to God, performing deeds in keeping with their *repentance.***

*Does not James say faith without works is dead (James 2:17)? Why should they not **believe** and turn to God, performing the deeds in keeping with that **belief?***

So that is it. Is this a valid understanding of at least some passages that involve salvation and repentance?

Comment: See https://www.onelook.com/?w=synecdoche

Comment: @fumanchu i see what you mean. I don't think that either word functions as a synecdoche of the other, though surely belief can function as a synecdoche for the entire appropriate response a believer has towards the gospel. Maybe repentance does the same.  I'll keep that in mind moving forward. Thanks.

Comment: As it's currently phrased, this is really a systematic theology question. To be on-topic here it would need to focus on a single specific passage, for the answer could be different for each.

Comment: It is our mind that moves our feet and our tongues. Faith, therefore, has to be the mind precursor of the act of repentance. Consequently, faith and repentance is not the same thing, although closely connected in people who has a gospel faith that is not dead, but alive in Christ.

Comment: The Bible (James 2:17) speaks about “dead faith”, so it appears that there is such a thing as faith without repentance. Repentance, which is to substitute negative acts and words with positive ones, is therefore just one possible result of a person’s faith. Consequently, the right order seems to be: 1. Believe. 2. Repent. 3. Be baptised in the Holy Spirit.

Comment: @Constantthin ***"Repentance, which is to substitute negative acts and words with positive ones..."*** You're using a different definition of repentance than what is in the NT Greek dictionary and what is in the Bible. Repentance is completely an internal state change and not a change in external behavior. See Paul's words that Gentile's **deeds** should match their **repentance,** once they repent and turn to God: 
*"...they should repent and turn to God, **performing deeds in keeping with their repentance."*** Acts 26:20 (ESV Strong's)

Comment: You are right, it is a change of mind that steers our better acts and words. It is that change of mind that I call “faith”. One could probably also call it living faith, in contrast to dead faith that doesn’t bring about a turning away from sin. Thx for asking for a clarification. By the way, turning to God is a positive act, involving  positive words. And “performing deeds in keeping with repentance” would be to zealously strive for more positive acts and words.

Comment: Thanks for being a person who is actually open to changing their own mind. **"One could probably also call it living faith, in contrast to dead faith."** Personally I like to keep definitions in my mind as simple as possible so as not to over-intepret. I find more gems in scripture that way. I imagine you can have vain repentance just as you can have vain belief if you don't hold fast to the gospel (1 Cor 15:1,2). This may explain the instructions, *"perform the deeds in keeping with repentance,"* after saying repent. It seems it's possible to repent, but not follow through or reverse repent.

Comment: **"By the way, turning to God is a positive act, involving positive words."** Here I think "turn to God" in this context is also a purely internal act. The "and" between "repent and turn to God" is an amplification, instead of a word connecting mutually exclusive concepts in a list. Repent, "change you mind," doesn't tell you what to change your mind towards. "Turn to God" does.  It's kind of like in Mark 1:15, the instructions to "repent and believe in the Gospel." Repent or "change your mind" doesn't tell you the end state of the mind change. "Believe in the Gospel" does.

Comment: Hi Austin, just to clarify, you would be able to **Edit** this question if you wish to have it brought on-topic and reopened. As Dannii has indicated, this is presently more of a systematic theology question. If you were able to hone it down to a good single case, perhaps where a single author uses the terms similarly, you could probably frame this in a way that was on-topic.

Comment: @SteveTaylor, I was thinking about simpy submitting a new question and focusing on Acts 3:19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If “repent” means an “about face” a “ change of direction” then an unbeliever that becomes a believer has in effect repented. Simple answers are best!

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean that the *meaning* of "believe" is "change direction". Many people believe in the existence of God long before they realise they need to repent. If you can't keep the two concepts distinct then you'll have a lot of trouble talking about anyone like that.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is the English way these two Greek words are usually translated.  Technically, there is no lexical overlap.

**μετανοέω ("repent")** refers to a change of mind or purpose; to feel remorse and be converted. (BDAG)

**πιστεύω ("Trust")** refers to entrusting oneself to an entity in complete confidence, "trust". (BDAG) Thus, the translation "believe" and "have faith in" are a bit too narrow.

It is immediately obvious that μετανοέω ("repent") refers to an event where one's life changes direction and purpose; and πιστεύω ("Trust") refers to an ongoing state of mind.  However, since trust in God must necessarily involve a change of mind and purpose (from being a sinner), these two verbs appear in close association.

For a longer discussion about the technicalities of NT words used in the process of salvation, see the appendix below.

APPENDIX - NT Soteriology

**Atonement**

This first phase of salvation is also called justification (= a declaring right or just), forgiveness, reconciliation, propitiation (or sacrifice of atonement in some versions), redemption, etc, (each of these terms offers a different analogue of, and insight into the atonement).  Atonement was accomplished by Jesus at the cross and decided upon by God “before the world began”, Matt 25:34, Heb 4:3, Rev 13:8.  This is why the atonement is sometimes called the eternal election – God decided to save all people (see “Election”) well before anyone sinned, solely by His grace born of His essential essence – love (1 John 4:8, 16).

This atonement is aimed at fixing the guilt and alienation of sin – it atones for wrong acts, without any input from sinners at all.  This means that Atonement is entirely “extrinsic” – done from outside a sinner.

The Bible also declares that God decided to make this reconciling atonement without reference to any human decision.  That is, Jesus died for the “ungodly” and “powerless” (Rom 5:6), not the righteous (Luke 5:32).  Paul makes the stark point that Jesus’ sacrifice was to demonstrate His righteousness (Rom 3:25, 26).  Therefore, the atonement was for all people – all are forgiven, all have been provided atonement!  (As we will soon see, this does not imply that all will be finally saved.)

While atonement is extrinsic and before conversion, the Holy Spirit still strives with sinners to bring them to conversion.

**Conversion**

“Conversion”, "commitment”, “deciding to be a disciple of Christ”, “sanctification”, “washing” (1 Cor 6:11) are all terms that describe what happens to a sinner at the point in the life when they realise their great need of God.  That is, the sinner’s life is “turned” in a different direction – toward God (Isa 45:22, Acts 2:38, 3:19, Rom 6:13, Luke 15:7, Isa 55:7, Eze 18:21, 33:11, Ps 51:13, Eph 4:22, etc).  This is the beginning of the Christian life and walk with Jesus.  In 2 Kings 11:17 conversion is described as an act of becoming a covenant people of God.

The step of conversion begins the process that is “intrinsic” that transforms the sinner to a person dedicated to serving God.

Note that a person’s decision to become a Christian by conversion is celebrated publicly by the rite of Baptism.  Acts 8:12, 16:33.

**Confession or Repentance**

Confession or repentance ALWAYS immediately follows conversion (1 John 1:9, Luke 15:32, Acts 17:30, Mark 1:15, Isa 55:7), and in the Bible conversion and confession/repentance are often used interchangeably because one always implies the other.  While confession does not inform God of our sin, it is an essential first step toward reformation of the life (2 Cor 7:9, 10, Ps 32:5, Prov 28:13, James 5:16).  That is, God cannot reform the sinner unless the sinner recognises that he/she is a sinner and confesses!

**Christian Life**

In modern theology, this stage is often called, unbiblically, “Sanctification”.  This stage of salvation is aimed primarily at fixing the corrupt human nature – removing the tendency to evil and our enjoyment of sin.  That is, as we “grow into Christ”, He begins to break the power of sin over us.

While this is a single functional stage of salvation, it involves several separate logical steps:

- Consecration, on-going commitment and Christian character development.  The Bible has numerous phrases to describe this including: “reflecting the Lord’s glory and being transformed into His likeness” (2 Cor 3:18), being “transformed by the renewing of your mind” (Rom 12:2), “follow after righteousness” (1 Tim 6:11), walking in the “newness of life” (Rom 6:4), “perfecting holiness” (2 Cor 7:1), “partaking in the divine nature” (2 Peter 1:4), “growing up into Christ” (Eph 4:15), “pressing toward the mark” (Phil 3:12-15), “being built up in Christ” (Col 2:7), “becoming complete in all the will of God” (Col 4:12), “fighting the good fight of faith” (1 Tim 6:12), “growing in grace” (2 Peter 3:18), “produce fruit in keeping with repentance” (Matt 3:8), “walk by the spirit and you will not gratify the desires of the flesh” (Gal 5:16), plus many more.  See “Imitation of Christ”.
- Perseverance of the Saints – a life-time commitment to serving Jesus and the Imitation of Christ.  The Bible calls this, “enduring to the end” (Matt 24:13, Mark 13:13, Heb 10:36), “remaining steadfast” (James 1:12, 1 Cor 15:58), “fighting the good fight” (2 Tim 4:7), “being strong in the Lord and in the strength of His might” (Eph 6:10), etc.  That is, the Christian life consists of much more than simply believing and being converted – it involves a lifetime commitment to Jesus called the Imitation of Christ and obedience to Jesus’ commandments.  Seven times in Rev 2 & 3 such people are called “overcomers” or “conquerors”.  See “Perseverance of the Saints”.
- Discipling and teaching others (Matt 28:19, Acts 1:8, 2 Tim 2:2) or being “fishers of men” (Matt 4:19, Mark 1:17).  See “Discipling”.

While it is obvious that the Christian life is lived by cooperation and consent of the Christian, it is still a miraculous work of transformation and renewal by God in us.  It is also God’s initiative.  “God is sovereign, Man is responsible”.

The New Testament makes an important distinction between the pre-conversion life and the post conversion life and describes these two lives as a “psychical” (or fleshly, Gr: sarx) life, vs a pneumatic (= spiritual) life.  That is the difference between a life controlled by the flesh and carnal desires, vs, a life controlled by spirit (in some places, the Holy Spirit).  Not all the references to a spirit lead life are direct references to the Holy Spirit but rather to the new spirit (= mind) of the converted Christian that has its source in the Holy Spirit.  See 1 Cor 2:14, 1 Cor 15:44-46, Gal 5:17, Jude 19, John 6:63, 1 Peter 3:18.

Important Note: The above is logically and theologically tidy but the New Testament frequently uses the terms “conversion”, “repentance” and “Christian life” as synonyms for each other.

**Glorification**

The term “glorification” as a noun does not appear in the Scriptures but is another modern theological term to describe what happens when God returns to rapture the saints.  It is also called “translation”, “rapture”, “resurrection of the saints”, etc, in modern terminology.  (See 1 Thess 4:16, 17, 1 Cor 15:12-56).  This is, when the mortal shall put on immortality and the corruption shall be made incorruptible and we shall live forever with Jesus.  Acts 23:8, Matt 22:30, Mark 12:25, Luke 20:36.

Comment: Him... i see your point. Do you think it would have been better to say, significant overlap in meaning?

Comment: @Austin - As stated above, I do not think there is any overlap in meaning - just an overlap in time - repentance (an event) begins trust in God (a life-long state)

Comment: Ok, let's see if you'd find this parallel in some sense: pulling out of your driveway is an event and driving is what you do till you reach your back destination, but the act of pull out of your driveway is actually driving. So they can refer to the same event. Similarly, repentance can refer to an event and belief is something you do a long time, till the end, it is still true that the act of believing something you didn't before is repentance by definition. In that case repentance would be the same as initial belief.

Comment: Is there any dictionary that defines belief as a relationship? Do I have to have a relationship with the president of France to trust him? Don't we have trust in a relationship or a relationship built on trust? Belief seems to be a prerequisite for a functional relationship and not a relationship itself.

Comment: @Austin - trust is ALWAYS built on a relationship of some kind, even if vicariously or based on second-hand information.  Trust never exists in a vacuum.

Comment: Ok. Even ***if** you're right and trust is ALWAYS built on a relationship. It would be the result of a relationship and not defined as a relationship. Either way it seems you're judging my understanding of belief/trust based on a definition that is not in any dictionary.

Comment: @Austin - I make no comments (or even thought) about judging your understanding.  I simply stated a well-known psychological fact that trust is based on a relationship.  Trust is NOT a relationship but is a component of a relationship.

Comment: @Dottard Thank you for this careful (and tidy!) summary. My read of scripture (and my observation in life) is that conversion is a process, rather than an event. Do you see it as an event? Or, rather, are you looking at a process and focusing in on the tipping point--and that's the "event" you have in mind?

Comment: @HoldToTheRod - Yes - conversion is a process, very long for some and very short for others like Paul.  However, there comes a point in that process where the person realizes that they need to make a commitment and turn their life around - that tipping point is also referred to as conversion - the turning around is the event alluded to above.

Comment: @Dottard, it seems like you're saying the tipping point of realizing the need to make a commitment is repentance. Did I get that right? I see repentance as the commitment decision and thus part of the commitment. Often repentance is described as making an 180-degree turn. When you have turned by committing your heart to the path of light you have repented. This is why, after the Jews realized they were wrong and were desperate to get right (asking what they should do), Peter commanded they repent (Acts 2:36-38), after they hit the tipping point you seemed to be describing.

Comment: @Austin - I am saying the tipping point - that place in life we make a commitment to serve God is the point of conversion.  Repentance is an on-going, life-long experience while we are still sinners

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to pin down your position, but it seems to change. First you say repentance is an event as opposed to trust that is a life-long state, but now you're saying that repentance is a life long experience, so a little confusing. 
   Which ever way you mean it, you seem to see it as something that happens to you (an event or an experience), instead of a willful commitment or decision. Is that right?

Comment: @Austin - my full statement is above - while ever we are sinner we still need confession and repentance.  Conversion is the the event that starts that life-long process.

Comment: Ok... I think what you are calling conversion is what the Bible is calling repentance as both are by definition, internal changes (Greek definition of repent). This is why in several passages non-Christians are told to repent but not told to have faith or believe.

Answer (score 1):

### Untangling the Steps to Salvation

**Should 'repent' and 'believe' be understood as often referring to the same [act] in the process of salvation?**

Answer: **Absolutely not.**

Repentance and belief are two separate steps in the full compliment of actions we must take for salvation. Repentance is not "belief" and belief is not "repentance." We cannot impose interpretations on texts that contradict other clear passages.

Faith is perfected by our works of obedience. ***Because*** of our faith -- belief in Christ -- we turn away from our sins (the Bible refers to this as “**repentance**”). We then acknowledges that Christ is the Son of God ("confession"), then finally upon baptism we are brought into union with the death of Christ -- as our emergence from the water is emblematic of His Resurrection. We too are then resurrected.

> **Romans 6:3-4**: "[Do] you not know that all of us who have been baptized into Christ Jesus have been baptized into His death? Therefore **we have been buried with Him through baptism into death, so that as Christ was raised from the dead through the glory of the Father, so we too might walk in newness of life**" (emphasis added).

How could we possibly get this wrong?

Yet, people everywhere may deny this reality. Christ's death, burial, and resurrection saves us. It’s baptism that brings us into union with all three. The death of Christ may, therefore, be appropriated to our lives. Note that **every time** you find the words “baptism” and “salvation” (or their equivalent terms) in the New Testament, baptism always comes first: there are no exceptions. This order is crucial. There are only six passages meet this qualification:

| Relevant Passage(s) | Text or Discussion |
| --- | --- |
| **Mark 1:4** and **Luke 3:3** | These refer to the baptism of John the Baptist “for the remission of sins” |
| **Acts 2:38** | “Repent and be baptized, everyone of you, for the remission of sins” |
| **Acts 22:16** | “Arise and be baptized… and wash away your sins” |
| **Mark 16:16** | “He that believes and is baptized shall be saved..” |
| **1 Peter 3:21** | “Corresponding to that, baptism now saves you…” |

The last verse, **1 Peter 3:21**, is clearly differentiating baptism from the removal of dirt and filth from the body. These are collectively what constitute "faith" or "belief." Repentance is but on step in a series of others. Note the following biblical steps for salvation:

|  | Plan of Salvation | Verses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Hear the Word | Romans 10:17, John 6:44-45 |
| 2. | Believe in Jesus as the Son of God | Hebrews 11:6, John 8:24, 20:30-31 |
| 3. | Repent of sin | Acts 2:38, Acts 17:30 |
| 4. | Confess that Jesus is the Son of God | Acts 8:36–37, Romans 10:9,10 |
| 5. | Be baptized for the remission of sins | Acts 2:38, 8:12, 8:16, 8:36, 10:48, 16:15, 16:30, 19:3-5, 22:16, Mark 16:16, Romans 6:3, Titus 3:5 |
| 6. | Live a life of obedient faith | 1 Peter 2:9, Colossians 1:22-23 |

The Letter of James tells that **even demons have heard the Word and believe** (Jas. 2:19). Belief or repentance (or both) alone are insufficient, as are any of the other conditions of salvation in isolation. Repentance is merely the third step in a sequence of steps toward salvation.

Comment: You actually hadn't shown any scripture contradicting that repentance can refer to the same thing as initial belief, and you ignore scripture contradicting your step presentation: Mark 1:15 puts repentance before the step of belief in the gospel.

Comment: @Austin Indeed, Mark 1:15 references repentance and faith (in that order) and has led some to conclude that **repentance precedes faith**. But this is easily refuted. No unbeliever has the capacity to repent because their repentance means nothing without belief in God. Faith unto salvation is a **penitent** faith and, therefore, such repentance is a **believing repentance**. We cannot simply isolate Mark's expression contrary to dozens of other passages that **do** lay out a sequence of steps to salvation. A person cannot repent if they have no belief through receipt of the Gospel.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124108/discussion-on-answer-by-xeno-should-repent-and-believe-be-understood-as-ofte).

Comment: @Xeno would you consider baptism by fire/Holy Ghost a step between 5 and 6, or do you bucket that under step 5?

Comment: @HoldToTheRod Good evening! Let me see. Well, 1 Pet. 1:7 tells us that the proof of our faith is "more precious than gold which is perishable, [and] even though tested by fire, may be found to result in praise and glory and honor before God." This would put the baptism of fire after our death, burial, and resurrection (baptism). I think. Based on Jesus' words in Jn. 3:5: "[Unless] one is born of water [immersion in water] and the Spirit [immersion in the Word] he cannot enter into the kingdom of God," it seems to me that these are baptism of water and the spirit respectively. Does that help?

Comment: @HoldTo There may be an easier way to phrase all of this. What I tried to communicate is that we: hear the Word, believe in Christ, repent of sin, confess during baptism and live faithfully. Maybe that clarifies things?

Comment: @Xeno a helpful summary, thanks. I've generally seen baptism by water and the spirit as two separate events...though I don't see why they couldn't happen one immediately after the other. I have in mind John the Baptist's teaching that he baptized by water but another (Jesus) was coming who would baptize by the spirit. Your list does indeed have much in common with Hebrews 6:1-2

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate events in my understanding. First repentance must take place or as it were a changing of the mind. After which there can be faith.

For how can one have faith when they haven’t changed their mind yet?

> “So faith comes from hearing, and hearing through the word of Christ.”
> ‭‭Romans‬ ‭10:17‬ ‭

The last event in this verse is faith. First someone must hear what is being said. They must then agree with the words and be willing to change their mind (repentance) and only afterwards can they display faith in what they have just heard. True faith can follow almost immediately after the mind has been changed but it’s still after and does not precede the changing of the mind.

> “and saying, “The time is fulfilled, and the kingdom of God is at hand; **repent and believe** in the gospel.””
> ‭‭Mark‬ ‭1:15‬ ‭

Notice the order of events in John 6

> “It is written in the Prophets, ‘And they will all be taught by God.’ **Everyone who has heard** and learned from the Father comes to me—”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭6:45‬ ‭

First someone must hear the good news, which takes time to explain. If they then decide to change their mind about what they consider to be true and are willing to accept the message of the gospel/Scriptures then

> “Truly, truly, I say to you, **whoever believes** has eternal life.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭6:47‬ ‭

Faith only occurs after hearing the message. Which means that faith does not precede the hearing. Once it is heard, and learned, the act of changing one’s mind/understanding, then faith will follow.

To put it in the negative. It’s impossible for someone to believe before they have repented, before they have changed their mind. At that point they have nothing to believe in regarding salvation. They still believe incorrectly.

Comment: You say, "They must then **agree** with the words and be willing to change their mind (repentance) and only afterwards can they **display faith** in what they have just heard." For the sake of clarity, is not agreeing with the word of God believing in the word of God? Is faith something you have inwardly that gives fruit to visible deeds or is it not faith until it is seen (displayed)?

Comment: Faith is agreeing, which then leads to a display of faith by acting on that which you believe to be true. That wasn’t my point. My point was that first one hears the word/good news/gospel/OT Scriptures with regard to a coming Messiah and salvation. Then they have to change their mind about how salvation is actually received. This could mean changing a lot of things, one at a time, and when the changing of the mind is complete the Father draws the person to Jesus who is the fulfillment of the Scriptures. If they believe **in Jesus** and call upon Him then they will be saved.

Comment: There is a changing of mind towards the process which requires faith in the Scriptures. True. But saving faith comes from calling upon Him. So faith in Jesus is after learning that He is the savior, which comes from hearing the gospel and believing it. You can hear the gospel, believe Jesus is the way and NEVER call upon him or delay calling upon Him (because the price is too high short-term. It’s actually higher not to, long term).

Comment: Ok, I see. Faith to you is calling on the Lord. What is calling on the Lord mean to you? I like to decouple meaning from religious language so that there is understanding since obviously this language means different things to different people.

Comment: Faith to me is not calling upon the Lord. Faith is **believing**... that according to the Scriptures that JESUS is the messiah. If they believe this, namely, that by putting their trust (FAITH) in Him they will be saved, they will call on Him to be saved *“And it shall come to pass that everyone who calls upon the name of the Lord shall be saved.’”* Acts‬‭2:21‬ ‭ Faith has to be placed in Jesus. **Faith means to trust**. I fully trust that Jesus will save me. I have faith that Jesus will let me enter into the kingdom to come. I trust that He will guide me. That’s all faith and it’s ongoing
‭‭

Comment: Calling upon the Lord means, denying oneself and subjecting oneself entirely under the leadership, lordship, and limitations of Jesus Christ. This means that upon receiving acceptance into salvation, into Christ, now I am to get to work in obedience. Getting in, yes is free, but once inside, it’s work time. The foolish virgins thought it was enough just to be a virgin, the guy with one mina/talent they thought it was enough that they had something. “For we are his workmanship, created in Christ Jesus **for good works**, which God prepared beforehand, that we should walk in them.”
‭‭Eph2:10‬

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems like your position is that repentance is the internal change that occurs before the internal change into trusting Jesus to save. The mind change that occurs before the change of mind into a person who puts their faith in Christ as their Lord. For me, that final mind change or internal change into a believer is what matters, and it's that internal change I believe Jesus & the Apostles are talking about when they tell people to repent, but they don't tell them to believe or have faith. I think repent is another way of saying stop what ur doing and be converted.